# Which Facebook Graph API version is used between URL and back-office?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We received a notification from Facebook that some of our games are still using GRAPH API v2.9 and that we should migrate to GRAPH API v2.10 or above.

I used the upgrade tool provided by Facebook and some games seem to need modifications before going to 2.10.

I checked which version of GRAPH API these apps are sending requests, and one of them uses GRAPH API 3.0 (I got this kind of URL on log: `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/{app_id}`).

In the back office, I see that we can change the Graph API version which should be called by all our users or `developper/tester/admin`. The default value is currently v2.9 and it will soon be v2.10 starting 22/07/2019.
I used test users whom calls should be directed to 3.3 and I didn't see any problem so far on my games.

So, I have 3 questions:

1. To simulate our apps behaviour in case of update, I created temporary test users (generated by your back office), set the Graph API to 3.3, log in with these accounts on devices (iOS and Android), and download/play our games. Is it the right way to test potentiel migration issues?
2. If my games send requests to 3.0, but in the back office, we set all call for users to 2.9, which version will be used?
3. And if we update the GRAPH API call to 3.3, and our app still makes its call to 3.0, which one will be used?

Comment: These settings override whatever API version might be specified in your calls, on the receiving end.

Comment: @misorude Thank you very much for your answer. Is it the same thing if the game asked for v2.5 (who doesnt exist anymore) ? Because I read on FB doc that if the requested API doesnt exist anymore, it will take the most obsolete one (for now the 2.9 and soon enough 2.10). It doesnt say if we update the API from the back office (for example 3.1), it will choose 3.1 instead of the most obsolete one. According to your answer, it should be the case though.

Comment: Of course it will chose the one you specify, anything else would not make sense.